# Using a method to puts variables

Tags: ruby

I want to use `capitalize` method and `puts` a string with the user input.

```
puts "What is your name?"
name = gets.chomp
puts "Hi, " name.capitalize "how are you?"
```

Here is the error after line 2:

> syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting $end puts "Hi, "
>   name.capitalize "how are you?"

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for [string literals](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings). Although it's valid (but uncommon) to concatenate string literals (e.g. `"Hi, " "flux" " how are you?"`), it doesn't work for variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to concatenate the strings or interpolate. Your options are:

```
puts "What is your name?"
name = gets.chomp
puts "Hi, " + name.capitalize + " how are you?"
```

or

```
puts "What is your name?"
name = gets.chomp
puts "Hi, #{name.capitalize} how are you?"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use string interpolation. Here is a [RubyMonk tutorial](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/chapters/5-strings/lessons/31-string-basics) you may enjoy.

```
puts "Hi, #{name.capitalize}, how are you?"
```

Comment: Thanks, I also found it can work with comma: puts "Hi, ", name.capitalize," how are you?" but I guess it's better to print in this case...

Comment: @flux that would result in 3 lines, because `puts` outputs a record separator (i.e. a newline) after each argument.